# Python Script for generating Certificate Authority

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, tls1.2

I want to create Root / Subordinate Certificate Authority files using Python Script.
Could you please let me know if there's any script available for this. Or point me to a separate module. I tried using ownca module from the link below. But it appears that it cannot create Subordinate(Intermediate) CA files. Though I was able to create Root CA Files.

https://ownca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

According to:

https://ownca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#creating-an-intermediate-certificate-authority

You can use the option intermendiate=True to create an intermediate certificate.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33009497)